# ActiveMQ broker stop is not working

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am getting :

> java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket:
>   nio://localhost:62626 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already
>   in use

My code :

```
DSMBrokerService broker = new SslBrokerService();
broker.addConnector("nio://localhost:62626");
broker.start();
broker.waitUntilStarted();

broker.stop();
broker.waitUntilStopped();

... (Do stuff)...

DSMBrokerService broker = new SslBrokerService();
broker.addConnector("nio://localhost:62626"); <- Exception
broker.start();
broker.waitUntilStarted()
```

Why does broker.stop() not unbind the Address ?

Answer (score 1):

Stopping the broker does not remove the connector. When you restart it again it fires up two connectors on that port.

Comment: I am actuality creating a new Instance before starting the Broker again. I also tried to remove the connectors after broker.stop();. Still - Getting the same error

Comment: The code in your question would say otherwise, you need to update the question with more complete information for help.